# Why the symbol defined in the shared library symbol is not used?

Tags: c++, c, shared-libraries, inline

I have a very simple shared library with two functions. hello1() is defined in the lib.cpp file, while hello2() is defined in the header (lib.hpp). hello1() and hello2() are not declared as inline.

I have then a test program that includes the header from the shared library and links against the shared library. The test.cpp program executes the two functions:
    #include "xdaq_headers/lib.h"

```
int main() {
  hello1();
  hello2();
}
```

As expected, When I change the hello1() definition in the lib.cpp and recompile the shared library, the changes are visible while executing the test program.

However, if I modify the hello2() definition in the header and recompile the shared library, then the changes are not made visible during the test program execution.

Only after recompiling test.cpp the changes are made visible.

My development platform is:

- Linux 2.6.18-348.12.1.el5 
  CEST 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
- gcc (GCC) 4.1.2

1) Why do I have this behavior?

2) How could I change the Makefile or header (but not the .cpp) in order to just require the recompilation of the library in order for the changes to take effect.

3) If the reason is that the function is inlined by the compiler (i.e. for being short?), how can I avoid that behavior? I have tried the following methods (and combinations)  w/o much success... although I do not discard that I'm doing something wrong:

- Add __attribute__ ((noinline)) like in the lib.hpp (g++ only):

```
    void hello2() __attribute__ ((noinline));

    void hello2() {
      asm("");
      std::cout
```

- Add the flag -fno-default-inline in the compiler flags.
- Add `asm("");` in the hello2() definition to simulate a side-effect.

lib.hpp:

```
#ifndef _mylib_lib_hpp_
#define _mylib_lib_hpp_

#include <iostream>

void hello1();

void hello2() {
  std::cout << "hello2(): first implementation" << std::endl;
}

#endif
```

lib.cpp:
    #include "xdaq_headers/lib.h"

```
#include <iostream>

void hello1() {
  std::cout << "hello1(): second implementation" << std::endl;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `hello2` is defined in the header, your test program will use that instead of the shared library's version. So if you modify the header, you'll need to recompile the test program. If you want to be able to just recompile the shared library, you'll need to move the definition (i.e. code) of `hello2` out of the header and into some other cpp file.